# CSS - Crop image displayed

Tags: html, css

I have a website where i have a image grid. For every line i have 4 images, which have the same display size. The problem is if i upload a image thats bigger than the space delimited, it gets resized. What I want to achieve is to have the image cropped instead of resized, so when i hover it expands and shows a bigger part of the image instead of just making it bigger.
I have tried using:

```
hidden:overflow;
object-fit: cover;
position: absolute;
clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
```

also tried setting negative margin.

**IMAGES** (sorry for bad quality)

**IMAGE I WANT TO UPLOAD**
[image: Image i want to upload]

**WHAT I GET**

[image: Display of the image]

**WHAT I NEED**

[image: Display I'm looking for]

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="img"><img src="..."></div>
    <div class="img"><img src="..."></div>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.img{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 23%;
}

.img img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari - Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.img:hover img {  
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.10); /* Safari - Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.10); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.10); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.10); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.10);
}
```

Is there anyway i can do this? The optimal dimensions of the image would be 420x420 px, but i don't want bigger pictures re-dimensioned.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something like this you're looking for?

```css
.grid{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  bacgkround: red;
}

.img{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 420px;
  height: 420px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img img{
  height: 300%;
  margin: 0 auto;

      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari - Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.img:hover img {  
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.10); /* Safari - Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.10); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.10); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.10); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.10);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKTXu.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform: translate`, where the `img` acts like `background-size: cover`

```css
.grid{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.img{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 23%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.img img{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQsYk.png" alt="some image here" />
  </div>

  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400" alt="some image here" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try through background-image

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>

.grid{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 23%;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKTXu.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.img:hover {
    background-size: 300%;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/qhgd96dc/